# How to retrieve the collection defined as a ICollection navigation property for a given entity in EF ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Database First approach to create models from existing database. I have two entities, say A and B. Entity A can hold a collection of Entity B, so in the model class for entity A, it has a ICollection of entity B and it is instantiated in entity A’s constructor as below:

```
class A
{
public A()
    {
        this.Bs = new HashSet<B>();

    }
public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the collection of B for the given A. How would I do that?

Say, entity A has a property named ID and I am able to pass ID of A from jqGrid to the controller action; in that case, how could I use the ID to retrieve the collection of B belonging to that particular ID.

I am really new to Entity Framework and MVC, so any suggestion is really helpful. Please don't mind if the question is so dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remeber correctly, supposing you can also access A from B you would have something like this:

`List<B> bs = YourDBContext.Bs.Where(b => b.A.ID == someID).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the where clause has an issue. (b.A.ID) didn't work, since b.As only gives native methods like (Add, Select, Where) and not it's properties. So, not able to compare the id's. Can you please take a look again at the syntax and check to see whether you can spot the issue?

Comment: How about this: `bs = YourDBContext.As.Where(a => a.ID = someID).Select(a => a.Bs).Single().ToList();`